# In Kotlin, why is the default argument not passed after the function being assigned to a variable?

Tags: kotlin

I created a function with default argument, then save the function to a variable.

But when I invoked the function through the variable, the default argument is not passed.

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    printNum()
    val fn = ::printNum
    fn(0)
    fn()    // error: no value passed for parameter 'i'
}
fun printNum(i: Int = 10) = println(i)
```

Comment: Thy to formalize a question. This is just a statement.

Comment: Function reference with default value is not supported at this moment. You may refer to this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8834).

Comment: @BakaWaii OK, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using a method reference. Your `fn` variable is of type `KFunction<Int, Unit>`. When you call `fn()` it's being compiled to `fn.invoke()`, which expects an integer as an argument here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I guess there is no way to invoke the function assigned to a variable, i.e. function reference with default argument?

Comment: That is not supported